# Access from Azure Function to Blob Storage on behalf of App Registration

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-app-registration

I want to access the Blob Storage from an Azure Function. I have multiple Azure Functions and want to manage all permissions at one place.

Therefore I have created an App-Registration AR1. This App-Registration I gave user_impersonation permission to Azure-Storage. And in the Access Control (AIM) of the Blob Storage I assigned the role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" to the Enterprise Application of the AR1. In my Azure function I enabled the MSI and in the Authentication I created the Microsoft Identity Provider for the App Registration I created earlier.
To link my Azure Function with AR1 I create user-defined role "blob storage contributor" and assigned this role to the MSI of the Azure Function in the corresponding Enterprise Application for AR1.

The Azure function in the code accesses Blob Storage with DefaultAzureCredentials(). So my idea - the Azure Function fetches a token from the Identity Provider with its MSI. The token claims that it was created for the App-Registration AR1 and the Azure Function then accesses the Blob Storage with that AR1-token "as the App-Registration AR1". The AR1 has the role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" and is allowed to read the blobs - so should my Function too. Unfortunately it does not work - I got the error "Exception occurs: This request is not authorized to perform this operation". Where is an error in my procedure? Or do I have to do something extra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. It seems it is not possible for the MSI flow when using DefaultAzureCredential() (I have not created any environment variables so that the MSI flow is used by DefaultAzureCredential()). It seems that my Azure Functions need to log in directly into the app registration. So, the application service principal flow via Environment needs to be activated for DefaultAzureCredential(). It can / must be done through Environment variables: AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_TENANT_ID and AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET. To do this, I had to create a Secret in the app registration AR1 (e.g. with the name MyFunctionSecret) and create these three variables in my Azure function's Configuration:

```
AZURE_CLIENT_ID = %App Registration Client ID%
AZURE_TENANT_ID = %TENANT ID of my function% 
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET = %MyFunctionSecret%
```

Now it works as desired. But I am not happy. Instead of SharedAccessKey / ConnectionString I have now the MyFunctionSecret which can expire and must be renewed / rotated too. I hoped with MSI's I could avoid this complicated rotation (with Azure Vault and ...) and all security would be managed by Azure for me.

Answer (score 0):

> By using App Registration with a managed identity. This helps to manage permissions for all Azure Functions in one place.

Steps to `setup Managed Identity`.

1. Create an `App Registration` in [Azure Active Directory and grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory?tabs=dotnet) it the necessary permissions to access Blob Storage.
2. Enable a managed identity for your Azure Function.
3. Grant the managed identity access to the `App Registration` in Azure AD.
4. Use the Azure SDK for .NET to authenticate to Blob Storage using the managed identity.

```
var cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var BlbSvcClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri("https://<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net"), cred);
```

Access to Blob storage for the App

[image]

Managed identity to Function App

[image]

[image]

[image]

For further information refer to [MSDoc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/dotnet/azure-sdk-authenticate-managed-identity?tabs=cli) and  [MSDoc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-dotnet-get-started?tabs=azure-ad).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rajesh M. Yes, this works, but it works, because the MSI of the Azure Function gets direct role assigment for the blob storage. And that's exactly what I don't want. In your workflow, I don't need an app registration at all. It will work without it. But I want the role assignement to be done only for the app registration and the Azure function then acts "on behalf" of the app registration.

Comment: Assigning roles to an app registration, use the Azure portal or programmatically using Microsoft Graph. Once added app roles in your application, and you can assign an app role to a client app by using the Azure portal or programmatically by using Microsoft Graph. When you assign app roles to an application, you create application permissions. Application permissions are typically used by daemon apps or back-end services that need to authenticate and make authorized API call as themselves, without the interaction of a user.

Comment: To assign app roles to an application by using the Azure portal, sign into the Azure portal, select Azure Active Directory, select App registrations, select the application to which you want to assign an app role, select API permissions, and then select Add a permission.
 For more information check this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps).

Comment: Assigning roles to an app registration is not a problem - I can do it in various ways - from the portal, or via Azure powershell. But I can't reach my primary goal, which I described in my question. Namely, that my Azure Functions can access Blob Storage on behalf of the  app registration.

Comment: Yes, Azure Functions can access Blob Storage on behalf of the app registration. You can use the Azure.Identity library to authenticate the app registration and access Blob Storage. You can also use the Azure.Storage.Blobs library to interact with Blob Storage.

Comment: The question was, how can I do this. My approach, described in the question, doesn't work.